# How can I remove a growing volatility from a time series?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, normalization

I have the following time series.

[image]

I want to transform this data so that the whole time series has more or less the same maximum and minimum amplitude.

Background is that I train a RL algorithm with these data. The growing amplitude makes the problem more complex as the only information the algorithm needs is the trend and the normalized amplitude. It has no use for the "trend" in the series.

You can use the following notebook to test this: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tmNJaiCLfW-gNnqGeRFdm7U8fzHMsSG6?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

This soultion assumesthe data is in a DataFrame. Also, some modifications may be neccecary but this solution should scale the data prior to index 7500 to the min and max values of index post 7500.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

mask_index = df.index>7500

scaler = MinMaxScaler((df[mask_index].min(), df[mask_index].max())

df.loc[~mask_index,:] = scaler.fit_transform(df.loc[~mask_index,:])
```

Comment: This assumes that the amplitude increases very suddenly after index 7500. Although it is fast, it still gradually increased between 7500 and 8200. That would mean that the range 7500-8200 would not be considered.
BTW the code you wrote leads to an exception:
'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()'

Comment: You are right, it does assume that and as per the question, the solution targeted that as well. I quote: "I want to transform this data so that the data until 7.5k has the same amplitude as the data following 7.5k." Consider rewriting the question.

Comment: I adjusted the code. Can you state which line causes the error?

Comment: I changed the question. Thanks for the hint. With your changes the error is now: '(array([ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False]), slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key' It is caused by the line 'df.loc[~mask_index,:] = scaler.fit_transform(df.loc[~mask_index,:])' You can try it in the linked jupyter notebook in my question ;-)